# Find string with only partially known value

Tags: javascript, html, string, tags, src

In an img tag, the src is not a constant value with each page load.

```
<img src="http:/foo.com/directory/id=(random alphanumeric string ID)">
```

The quantity of the alphanumeric string generated by the network that created it is generally just over 200 characters.

If this were the only img tag, I would just do getElementsByTagName, but there are plenty of img across the page source. Is there a way to target a tag source by only *partial* src contents, and then .innerHTML the ID number *only*? I imagine it would have to be written in such a way that it goes until it encounters the " at the end.

Comment: In other words: you want to replace what's followed by `id=` ? Or is it the proposed solution?

Comment: I need to grab that ID number.

Comment: You need to grab it without knowing what it is, or you need to target it as a partial of the source ?

Comment: In this case I believe the proposed solution is correct, although you could use regular expressions instead of indexOf to be a little more safer

Comment: btw. can anyone tell me if i should remove my comments now?

Comment: @adeneo - I need to grab it without knowing the ID value. Honestly, I can just grab the whole "src" and it would be fine but because it's not the only img tag (this is the only one though that has the id number in it), as I said I can't just target it using getElementsByTagName. I saw you placed a method for that down below. Super explanatory and easy to comprehend for me. Thanks :)

Comment: You want to grab the img element having part of the src attribute?

Comment: @theFX I'm looking to get the value of id=

Comment: Ok, but what infomation you have? Part of the src attribute? The link? Only one `img` selector? What?

Comment: @theFX it was already pretty much answered below, but as I said in my opening post... There are more than one img tag in the page code but only one has a src that has the "id=" that I'm looking for. It looks just like I posted above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just iterate and check the `src`

```
var id      = 'random alphanumeric string ID';
var images  = document.querySelectorAll('img');
var match   = null;

for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    if ( images[i].src.indexOf(id) !== -1 ) {
        match = images[i];
        break;
    }
}

// An image doesn't have innerHTML, but if it had, this is where you'd set it
```

Somewhat fancier way to do the same thing

```
var id = 'random alphanumeric string ID';

var match = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img')).filter(function(img) {
    return img.src.indexOf(id) !== -1;
});
```

if you wanted to replace that part

```
match.src = match.src.replace(id, 'something else');
```

if you don't know what the ID is and you need to get all the ID's

```
var ids = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img')).map(function(img) {
    var id = img.src.match(/\/id\=(.+)/);
    return id && id.length ? id.pop() : '';
});
```

Comment: i think he means more something like `...src.matches(/a nice regex/)`

Comment: @xerx593 - I'm not sure what that means, there is no `matches` and checking if a string contains a string is done with `indexOf` ?

Comment: @adeneo you are so much better than me ... i wanted to post something.
But when im looking at your code im just feeling like a total noob :-))

Comment: This is actually sort of what I was thinking. I knew a for loop would be in there for some function. My initial thought was maybe I could locate the position of the "id=" and then just create a new variable and then append each subsequent character to the variable and have it end when it encounters a quotation mark. I've just been having trouble making that thought materializing functionally into my code so thought there had to be a more efficient way to do it. Maybe my first train of thought could work as well, but reading your method @adeneo I think that is much clearer.

Comment: @Redrif - all it takes is a little practice ... and you'll still feel that way. I feel like that all the time.

Comment: @adeneo curious about something I just noticed now that I didn't yesterday. When I log "ids" (which I changed for purposes of my variable names) to the console, I do get the value I'm looking for, but there are also a varying amounts of commas the precede it each time I load the page (2-4). When I look at the HTML for the page, there are no commas in the id=(random ID) as there shouldn't be. I'm assuming the commas are generated from the function but can't figure out why. Example: my last console log returned ,,,,1fHJpZD01NDVjYjBjMS00YzFiLTQyMmYtODNjYS03NjgwMjQyMDhhMjF8cnQ9MTQyOTY1Mzc2Nn...etc

Comment: Then there are other images on the page without an ID. The last function that gets the ID's iterates over all images, if you want to filter out the empties you can do -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/cp5e75gq/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of selector in jQuery

```
  $("img[src$='id="+ id +"']").css({'border-color':'red', 'border-width':1, 'border-style':'solid'});
```

Will check if the src atribute ends with 'id=?'

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right, you're trying to grab the "id=" which is on the `src` attribute of a `img` having only part of the `src` attribute.

It can be done like this:

```
img[src*='part of the src attribute']
```

Then you'll have the `img` element, you just have to get the `src` attribute, and get everything after the "id=".

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/dsoqrqdg/